# Diff between web routing and api routing in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I read many post regarding new concept about api routing. I understood that api routing is used for mobile platforms but is there code level difference between them

In `RouteServiceProvider` i can see

```
/**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'web',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/web.php');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'api',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            'prefix' => 'api',
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/api.php');
        });
    }
```

As per this web route uses

> These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.

api route

> These routes are typically stateless.

My question is

1. What does it mean `stateless` in api route ?
2. Web routing uses  `session state`, `CSRF protection`. Does it mean api routing is not using session state, CSRF protection ?
3. Laravel 5.3 uses seperate `web` and `api` routing, is there any advantages  ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. What does it mean `stateless` in api route ?

It means server doesn't save client 'state' between requests. Here is couple words about REST [What exactly is RESTful programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)

2. Web routing uses  `session state`, `CSRF protection`. Does it mean api routing is not using session state, CSRF protection ?

All is possible but not required. You still can using sessions etc, but this is a REST principles violation.

3. Laravel 5.3 uses seperate `web` and `api` routing, is there any advantages

It's just for your convenience. In Laravel 5.2 you need specify middleware for routes like ['web'] or ['api'] but it doesn't required anymore. In 5.3 routes stored in separated files and specify routes middleware not required.

Comment: @aleksejjj.Thanks for the answer

Comment: It's my pleasure. I hope you find it useful.